# How to put text on the Facebook wall without FB Api?

Tags: android, facebook

I have a huge problem with putting some data on the user Facebook wall. 
I'm using typical :

```
String response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
```

But it constatly gives me an output :

```
07-31 12:28:44.651: V/status(23104): {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

So I guess strucutre of my code won't allow me to use this api method.
Do you know how to send POST data without FB API ?

Comment: Without authentication you cant make any call to Facebook graph API and you need Facebook SDK for that.

Comment: before calling this, refresh you connection with facebook, Just call the method loginFacebook() which you made to login users. I is working for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Of all You will need to authenticate your users through Facebook API. Without authentication and proper permission you will not be able to publish on users timeline or read posts from latter. The aim of authentication is to obtain an `access_token` which you will need in your case. 
If you want to do so here are some documentations you can start with: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/